# c++ : updating progress bar from std::async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, progress-bar

It is an all time classics problem, but to be honest I haven't found a simple example of how to update a progress bar by an async function call.

lets say I have(not the accurate code, but the main flow is like this):

```
int main (){

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();


    for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
      std::shared_future<MyObj*> f = std::async(std::launch::async, myFunc, 
       myFunctionArgument);
      futures.push_back(f);
    }


    std::vector<MyObj*> resCollects;
    for (std::shared_future<MyObj*> f : futures)
    {
      MyObj* res = f.get();
      resCollects.push_back(res);
    }
return;
}
```

The computationally heavy task that has to be carried out async
the job per core is here:

```
    MyObj* myFunc (MyFunctionArgument myFunctionArgument){
     for(int i=0; i < myFunctionArgument.size(); i++){
       doLongCalculations(myFunctionArgument.data);
       //HOW DO I UPDATE THE PROGRESS BAR THAT A SMALL FRAGMENT OF THE TASK HAS BEEN 
       //COMPLETED? updateProgressBar(int i);
     }
    }
```

The class ProgressBar is in a simple form:

```
    class ProgressBar{
      private: 
                int totalTasks;
                int currentProgress;
     public:
       void updateProgressBar(int i){
         cout<<" The current progress is: " << i << "out of "<< 
     totalTasks;
        }
    
    }
```

Supposing I have already implemented a simple class of progress bar which takes an integer and updates the percentage of the total task(of which I know the total size) that has been completed, what's the basic design of updating that progress bar? Where should i call "updateProgressBar(int i) from? I need a very simple example to understand the design of the solution how to emit and receive progress.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by "update progress bar". E.g.: in QT you should emit a signal previously connected with `Qt::QueuedConnection`. In some other situation maybe you need to wake up `std::condition_variable` to tell the progress bar to update itself. The question needs more details.

Comment: I had worked a lot with Qt some years ago and it was very helpful for such cases. What I am looking here is the basic design of how to update the progress bar function from an asynchronous call. I updated a little bit the code so it is  more informative. Perhaps the design I have done is completely wrong, so if there is suggestion of how to make it work please send some useful link